# Unable to pass array value, which is stored in context variable in http body in talend job

Tags: java, http, talend

```
{\"request\": \"hkvhkvh\", \"para\": {\"api_auth_token\": \"biyvglyvlyvlbhikjbvh\", \"user_id\": 35641, \"company_ids\": [30945], \"reference_id\": \"+context.reference_id+\"}}
```

In above http body company_ids is array value. if we hardcoded that value we are able to fetch data but if we pass context variable instead of hardcode value like context.company_id. we getting error like bad request.
kindly help me to solve this issue.

I tried like this.

```
{\"request\": \"hkvhkvh\", \"para\": {\"api_auth_token\": \"biyvglyvlyvlbhikjbvh\", \"user_id\": 35641, \"company_ids\": [context.company_ids], \"reference_id\": \"+context.reference_id+\"} }
```

Comment: What component are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm surprised that your job actually builds but if you're constructing the payload via a simple string.

Technically, you should be escaping the quotes and injecting the context variables through string manipulation.

Without knowing the exact component you're using, I'd be doing something like this ...

```
"{ \"request\": \"hkvhkvh\", \"para\": {\"api_auth_token\": \"biyvglyvlyvlbhikjbvh\", \"user_id\": 35641, \"company_ids\": [" + context.company_ids + "], \"reference_id\": " + context.reference_id + " } }"
```